# Socket connection - Blocked ports on network carrier

Tags: android, sockets

I am developing an Android application that uses socket connections as part of its messaging system. However I have hit a problem that all ports (except the standard email/http etc ones) seems to be blocked by the network carriers in the UK. Am I doing something incorrectly? As it would appear that socket connections are pretty much useless over any mobile carriers network.

Comment: If you can surf the web and read Facebook from your mobile device then I would doubt "all" ports are blocked. Can you explain what you are actually trying to do and what errors you are getting? Perhaps post some code that is not working...

Comment: Sorry, I shouldn't have said all ports. Mail and http ports are obviously open. However apart from the standard ports, the rest seem to be closed.

Comment: Hardly any mobile provider will permit inbound connections, for both technical and policy reasons.  If they are blocking things like ssh outbound that is very unfortunate, at any rate, you can build your interaction with your server to either literally be or at least resemble http traffic.  If they are playing proxy games you may need ssl.

Comment: I don't know what the Android programming model is like for sockets, but I think I know what the OP is trying to achieve and using HTTP is probably not going to work for reasons of synchronicity. The original question, I believe, is can you initiate TCP/UDP connections FROM the Android device to an arbitrary port on a server through the common mobile carriers in the UK? The reason I'm interested in the answer is because I have a similar question about mobile carriers in Australia, so if anybody has any insights, it would be greatly appreciated.